# Error while calling stored procedure through php. Literal does not match format string

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am using Oracle 10g Express Edition with PHP codeigniter.

I have a table tbl_movie:-

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_movie (movie_id NUMBER(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  movie_image VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  language_id NUMBER(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl_language(language_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  showtime_id NUMBER(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES tbl_showtime(showtime_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  movie_sdate DATE NOT NULL,
  movie_edate DATE NOT NULL,
  movie_add_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Now I have created a procedure by running it through the Oracle Command Line:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
        insertMovie (id IN NUMBER, title IN VARCHAR2, image IN VARCHAR2, language IN NUMBER, showtime IN NUMBER, sdate IN DATE, edate IN DATE, adate IN DATE, message OUT NUMBER) 
    IS
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_movie (movie_id, movie_title, movie_image, language_id, showtime_id, movie_sdate, movie_edate, movie_add_date) 
            VALUES ( id, title, image, language, showtime, TO_DATE(sdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE(edate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE(adate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
            message := 1;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            message := 0;
        END;
/
```

This is the code from my codeigniter controller:-

```
public function testMovie()
{
    $insertData['movie_id'] = 1;
    $insertData['movie_title']= 'test';
    $insertData['movie_image']= 'rfgt';
    $insertData['language_id']= 1;
    $insertData['showtime_id']= 1;
    $insertData['movie_sdate']= '2017-02-24 00:00:00';
    $insertData['movie_edate']= '2017-02-27 00:00:00';
    $insertData['movie_add_date']= '2017-02-20 00:00:00';
    $this->load->model('oracle_model');
    $return = $this->oracle_model->add_movie('movie',$insertData,'');   
}
```

And this is the model function which is for calling the procedure:-

```
function add_movie($entity,$insertData,$time)
{
    print_r($insertData);
    $conn   = oci_connect("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx");
    if(!$conn)
    {
        echo "connect failed".oci_error();
    }   
    else
    {   
        echo "connect done at".date('d-m-y');

        // calling stored procedure insertMovie
        $insertMovieProcedureSQL = "BEGIN insertMovie(:id, :title, :image, :language, :showtime, :sdate, :edate, :adate, :message); END;";
        $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $insertMovieProcedureSQL);

        //  Bind the input parameter
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':id',$insertData['movie_id']);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':title',$insertData['movie_title']);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':image',$insertData['movie_image']);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':language',$insertData['language_id']);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':showtime',$insertData['showtime_id']);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':sdate',$insertData['movie_sdate']);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':edate',$insertData['movie_edate']);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':adate',$insertData['movie_add_date']);

        // Bind the output parameter
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':message',$message);

        oci_execute($stmt);
        // $message is now populated with the output value
        echo "$message\n";
    }   
}
```

When I am running the function, I am getting the following error:-

```
oci_execute(): ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at line 1
```

When I tried to run the procedure by eliminating all the date datatype columns, the code is running fine. I think the main problem is with the Date columns.

But when I run this query from the command line, data gets successfully inserted:-

```
INSERT INTO tbl_movie (movie_id, movie_title, movie_image, language_id, showtime_id, movie_sdate, movie_edate, movie_add_date) 
            VALUES ( 2, 'title', 'image', 2, 3, TO_DATE('2017-02-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('2017-02-27 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('2017-02-20 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
```

What am I doing wrong? I am stuck for nearly 4 hours.

Comment: sir, I am not an expert but just create an store procedure in PHPMyAdmin and I also get stuck for not giving correct delimiter in stored procedure so may you can try checking your delimiter. @Saswat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure parameters `sdate` etc. are of `DATE` data type. Within your procedure, you apply `TO_DATE( ...., 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')` to them.

`TO_DATE` is used to convert **strings** to dates, not **dates** to dates. If you apply `TO_DATE` to a date, Oracle first converts the date to a string, so that it can be passed to `TO_DATE`. Unfortunately, when Oracle does that implicit conversion, it doesn't use the same format model you have in `TO_DATE`; rather, it uses the `nls_date_format` of the session that invoked the procedure. Which is not the same as the model in `TO_DATE` - which causes the error you saw.

There are two ways to solve this. One is to not use `TO_DATE(sdate, ...)` but use just `sdate` in the `INSERT` statement. `sdate` and the others are dates already (if they were passed correctly as dates to the procedure in the first place).

The second is, if in fact you meant that the arguments are passed in as strings, don't declare them as `DATE` in the procedure declaration; declare them `VARCHAR2`. (And make double-sure those strings are **exactly** in the correct format - you should be able to control that from the front-end.)

Whenever you see `TO_DATE(....)` applied to a `DATE` input, expect an error like the one you saw. Conversely, whenever you see an error like that, suspect code like `TO_DATE(....)` applied to a date.

**Added**:  There is also another possibility. If in fact you are passing strings to the procedure, Oracle must convert them to dates (because they are declared as such). If the strings aren't exactly in the format of the `nls_date_format` of the session invoking the procedure, this initial conversion of the parameters from strings to dates will fail and the `INSERT` statement won't even be reached.

Comment: Lot better explanation then mine :)

Comment: @Utsav - I just realized my explanation may not be complete... it is also possible the OP is passing in strings, not dates - and the whole thing fails right at the beginning, it never even hits the INSERT statement, since Oracle will try to convert the strings to dates using NLS_DATE_FORMAT and that may fail if the strings aren't exactly the right format.

Comment: Didn't know how it works internally. Thanks for the info on `nls_date_format`. (+1) Coming back to resolution of the error, if you see his code, then it looks like he is indeed passing the string. So if we change the datatype of input parameter to string, the problem will be solved. I remember working on a similar kind of solution. Anyways, lets wait for him to comment.

Comment: @Utsav - I only see "when I am running the function, I get the following error:" - I don't see **how** he calls the function (in particular, I don't see how he passes the parameters; functions are used to pass parameters from a front-end application, otherwise there should be no need for a function in the first place). In any case, I offered that solution, too - you can see it in my answer.

Comment: @mathguy, actually I am using the php date() function, which provide date as string. The mysql datetime accepts values returned by date() function. But it's not the same with oracle. That's why I was having issue. Amyways, you solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the datatype of input parameters from `date` to `varchar`. In current scenario, you are basically applying `to_date` on a `date` datatype. Once you replace `date` with `varchar`, your rest of the logic should work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
        insertMovie (id IN NUMBER, title IN VARCHAR2, image IN VARCHAR2, language IN NUMBER, showtime IN NUMBER, sdate IN VARCHAR2, edate IN VARCHAR2, adate IN VARCHAR2, message OUT NUMBER) 
    IS
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_movie (movie_id, movie_title, movie_image, language_id, showtime_id, movie_sdate, movie_edate, movie_add_date) 
            VALUES ( id, title, image, language, showtime, TO_DATE(sdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE(edate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE(adate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
            message := 1;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            message := 0;
        END;
/
```